# Dropping columns from a df using a vector of their indices

Tags: r, subset

I have a huge df whose columns contain genetic data (dosage counts). I have a list (a vector) of the index of the columns which are of no use for my analyses (they display only one value for all the rows) and I am trying to subset the df using this information.
I went through some attempts (apply(), subset(), for loops), but I seem to be missing the point.

```
df <- data.frame(
  k = c(0,1,1,0,0,1), d = c(0,1,0,2,0,1), p = c(0,0,0,0,0,0), 
  f = c(1,1,-9,0,0,0), t = c(0,0,-9,0,0,0), q = c(0,-9,0,0,0,0), 
  y = c(1,0,1,0,1,0), r = c(0,0,0,0,0,-9) )

index <- vector(3,5,6,8)

>df

  k d p  f  t  q y  r
1 0 0 0  1  0  0 1  0
2 1 1 0  1  0 -9 0  0
3 1 0 0 -9 -9  0 1  0
4 0 2 0  0  0  0 0  0
5 0 0 0  0  0  0 1  0
6 1 1 0  0  0  0 0 -9
```

What I'm trying to get

````
>df

  k d  f y
1 0 0  1 1
2 1 1  1 0
3 1 0 -9 1
4 0 2  0 0
5 0 0  0 1
6 1 1  0 0```
````

Comment: You can just use `df[-index]`.

Comment: It works just fine, thanks! I did really walked around that